# Return to a previous session id

Tags: php, zend-framework, session-cookies

We have a legacy (php) aplication, accepting file uploads and they are stored at a path depending on the session id. Now we had to provide a very simple API for this webapp, where through an iOS api (iPad) a file upload is performed. We return an url which the customer will open in an embedded webkit window.

Because the sessions from the upload and view actions are different, we thought to grab the session parameter and return it in our response from the file upload. Then the client gets redirected to that url, we set the session id to the previous id and continue to the page the customer can continue the work.

Apparently, nothing I tried works. We use Zend Framework 1, but that shouldn't really matter. I tried:

1. Setting a Set-Cookie header (this results in a cookie containing two PHPSESSID values)
2. Use a `setcookie("PHPSESSID", $session, 3600)` to set the PHPSESSID
3. Use the Zend http Reponse with a `setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=....', true)`

The last two options just don't do anything, like I didn't set the session at all. How can I solve this? We actually can't touch the legacy code base that much to modify its working and change the way the path resolving works for file uploads.

So, the flow is:
Request to api.myapp.tld -> Response with a string in body -> Open webkit window with this response string as location -> Request is performed -> Response with a Redirect header **and a method to set the cookie to something different** -> Webkit performs redirect -> Customer gets to a page with same session ID as the first request to api.myapp.tld.

If there is an alternative to set the session id, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by something simpler. The session was related to the path like this `/path/to/location/ . $sessionId`. When the second session was started, I simply renamed the directory from the old session to the new one. Simple and fast to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

That's not trivial to debug, but you have some options. I'm not fluent with Zend Framework 1.x, so this is not framework specific (frameworks sometimes add stuff on top), but PHP specific.

In PHP a session is identified by two things:

1. [Name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) (example: a common default name is `PHPSESSID`)
2. [ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) (that is the random "number")

The Name allows to use multiple sessions at once, while the ID identifies the session in specific.

It sounds a bit you need to use two session IDs in parallel. I suggest you make the script that needs to deal with the legacy session to have another sessions name than your current script.

You can then pass in the legacy/old session id by using the other session name *while* your current session can remain as is.

I hope this information is helpful. If you have got problems to implement that, please ask.